# Github - what is red X, green check mark in view of branches

Tags: github

What is the green check mark/red X?

Is it whether it builds or not?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the desktop page, it shows more detail when you click on the X, but basically some automated steps after were not successful:

[image]

Comment: You can access this on the Desktop version on mobile browser as well